# NASM: Provide constant value at compile time

Tags: assembly, command-line-interface, nasm

Say I have some generic x86 NASM code:

```
%define Constant 123
mov si, Constant
```

The problem is that the constant value `Constant` is not yet known when the assembly is written. By this I mean that the value for the constant should be provided when the file is assembled. In my case the constant I require depends on the size of a text-file.

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking through the NASM manual I found no command-line option for the assembler that did what I required. My solution is pretty simple. The following script shows how I solved the issue.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Could be replaced by any other way of getting the constant value; this gets a file's size
fileSize=`stat --printf="%s" my_file.txt`

# Write the constant definition to a temporary file
printf "%%define FILE_SIZE %s\n" $fileSize > tmp

# Append the rest to the temporary file 
cat my_asm.asm >> tmp

# Assemble the file and name the output correctly
nasm tmp -o my_asm.out

# Remove the temporary file
rm tmp
```

Comment: Won't the `-D` option do what you need?

Comment: And/or `%include` to at least save the `cat`-onto-a-temporary in the build process.

Comment: @PeterCordes I like your idea. Your way includes a way to see inside the ASM file that something will be appended. +1

Comment: @MargaretBloom I somehow missed that parameter. I agree that it does what I need, however I fear that when using more than just a few constants the file will become hard to read. With only a handful of constant definitions `-D` is definitely better. Thanks for the help!